# Alembic async SQLAlchemy OperationalError during migration to the database

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, database-migration, alembic

I initialized the asynchronous alembic directory for base migrations, specified the base path in the `.ini` (I created the migration for an unchanged model and loaded it successfully and the file recorded recent changes, so I think the path is correct), and also specified target_metadata in `env.py`

The problem arose when I changed the column in the model class (added the Optional annotation)

To create the migration I used:
`alembic revision --autogenerate -m "message"`

To load the migration I used:
`alembic upgrade head`

The following **exception** occurred just while executing the last one:

```
(venv) PS C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot> alembic upgrade head                                                      
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 5fefb216ecaf -> 9bce8e04e73c, make presence column in Mark Optional
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1969, in _exec_single_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 922, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\sqlite\aiosqlite.py", line 146, in execute
    self._adapt_connection._handle_exception(error)
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\sqlite\aiosqlite.py", line 298, in _handle_exception
    raise error
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\sqlite\aiosqlite.py", line 128, in execute
    self.await_(_cursor.execute(operation, parameters))
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_concurrency_py3k.py", line 130, in await_only
    return current.driver.switch(awaitable)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_concurrency_py3k.py", line 195, in greenlet_spawn
    value = await result
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiosqlite\cursor.py", line 48, in execute
    await self._execute(self._cursor.execute, sql, parameters)
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiosqlite\cursor.py", line 40, in _execute
    return await self._conn._execute(fn, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiosqlite\core.py", line 133, in _execute
    return await future
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiosqlite\core.py", line 106, in run
    result = function()
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "ALTER": syntax error

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\venv\Scripts\alembic.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\config.py", line 641, in main
    CommandLine(prog=prog).main(argv=argv)
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\config.py", line 631, in main
    self.run_cmd(cfg, options)
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\config.py", line 608, in run_cmd
    fn(
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\command.py", line 403, in upgrade
    script.run_env()
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\script\base.py", line 583, in run_env
    util.load_python_file(self.dir, "env.py")
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\util\pyfiles.py", line 95, in load_python_file
    module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\util\pyfiles.py", line 113, in load_module_py
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)  # type: ignore
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\migrations\env.py", line 91, in <module>
    run_migrations_online()
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\migrations\env.py", line 85, in run_migrations_online
    asyncio.run(run_async_migrations())
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\migrations\env.py", line 77, in run_async_migrations
    await connection.run_sync(do_run_migrations)
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\asyncio\engine.py", line 891, in run_sync
    return await greenlet_spawn(fn, self._proxied, *arg, **kw)
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_concurrency_py3k.py", line 202, in greenlet_spawn
    result = context.switch(value)
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\migrations\env.py", line 61, in do_run_migrations
    context.run_migrations()
  File "<string>", line 8, in run_migrations
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\runtime\environment.py", line 948, in run_migrations
    self.get_context().run_migrations(**kw)
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\runtime\migration.py", line 627, in run_migrations
    step.migration_fn(**kw)
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\migrations\versions\9bce8e04e73c_make_presence_column_in_mark_optional.py", line 23, in upgrade
    op.alter_column('marks', 'presence',
  File "<string>", line 8, in alter_column
  File "<string>", line 3, in alter_column
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\operations\ops.py", line 1943, in alter_column
    return operations.invoke(alt)
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\operations\base.py", line 445, in invoke
    return fn(self, operation)
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\operations\toimpl.py", line 53, in alter_column
    operations.impl.alter_column(
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\ddl\impl.py", line 241, in alter_column
    self._exec(
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\ddl\impl.py", line 207, in _exec
    return conn.execute(construct, multiparams)
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1416, in execute
    return meth(
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\ddl.py", line 181, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_ddl(
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1528, in _execute_ddl
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1848, in _execute_context
    return self._exec_single_context(
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1988, in _exec_single_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2344, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    raise sqlalchemy_exception.with_traceback(exc_info[2]) from e
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1969, in _exec_single_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 922, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\sqlite\aiosqlite.py", line 146, in execute
    return await self._conn._execute(fn, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiosqlite\core.py", line 133, in _execute
    return await future
  File "C:\MyFolder\python\discord\logika bot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiosqlite\core.py", line 106, in run
    result = function()
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "ALTER": syntax error
[SQL: ALTER TABLE marks ALTER COLUMN presence DROP NOT NULL]
```

**My env.py file:**

```py
import asyncio
from logging.config import fileConfig

from sqlalchemy import pool
from sqlalchemy.engine import Connection
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import async_engine_from_config

from alembic import context

from orm.models import Base

# this is the Alembic Config object, which provides
# access to the values within the .ini file in use.
config = context.config

# Interpret the config file for Python logging.
# This line sets up loggers basically.
if config.config_file_name is not None:
    fileConfig(config.config_file_name)

# add your model's MetaData object here
# for 'autogenerate' support
# from myapp import mymodel
# target_metadata = mymodel.Base.metadata
target_metadata = Base.metadata

# other values from the config, defined by the needs of env.py,
# can be acquired:
# my_important_option = config.get_main_option("my_important_option")
# ... etc.


def run_migrations_offline() -> None:
    """Run migrations in 'offline' mode.

    This configures the context with just a URL
    and not an Engine, though an Engine is acceptable
    here as well.  By skipping the Engine creation
    we don't even need a DBAPI to be available.

    Calls to context.execute() here emit the given string to the
    script output.

    """
    url = config.get_main_option("sqlalchemy.url")
    context.configure(
        url=url,
        target_metadata=target_metadata,
        literal_binds=True,
        dialect_opts={"paramstyle": "named"},
    )

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


def do_run_migrations(connection: Connection) -> None:
    context.configure(connection=connection, target_metadata=target_metadata)

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


async def run_async_migrations() -> None:
    """In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """

    connectable = async_engine_from_config(
        config.get_section(config.config_ini_section, {}),
        prefix="sqlalchemy.",
        poolclass=pool.NullPool,
    )

    async with connectable.connect() as connection:
        await connection.run_sync(do_run_migrations)

    await connectable.dispose()


def run_migrations_online() -> None:
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode."""

    asyncio.run(run_async_migrations())


if context.is_offline_mode():
    run_migrations_offline()
else:
    run_migrations_online()
```

**My alembic.ini file:**

```
# A generic, single database configuration.

[alembic]
# path to migrations scripts
script_location = migrations

# template used to generate migrations file names; The default value is %%(rev)s_%%(slug)s
# Uncomment the line below if you want the files to be prepended with date and time
# file_template = %%(year)d_%%(month).2d_%%(day).2d_%%(hour).2d%%(minute).2d-%%(rev)s_%%(slug)s

# sys.path path, will be prepended to sys.path if present.
# defaults to the current working directory.
prepend_sys_path = .

# timezone to use when rendering the date within the migrations file
# as well as the filename.
# If specified, requires the python>=3.9 or backports.zoneinfo library.
# Any required deps can installed by adding `alembic[tz]` to the pip requirements
# string value is passed to ZoneInfo()
# leave blank for localtime
# timezone =

# max length of characters to apply to the
# "slug" field
# truncate_slug_length = 40

# set to 'true' to run the environment during
# the 'revision' command, regardless of autogenerate
# revision_environment = false

# set to 'true' to allow .pyc and .pyo files without
# a source .py file to be detected as revisions in the
# versions/ directory
# sourceless = false

# version location specification; This defaults
# to migrations/versions.  When using multiple version
# directories, initial revisions must be specified with --version-path.
# The path separator used here should be the separator specified by "version_path_separator" below.
# version_locations = %(here)s/bar:%(here)s/bat:migrations/versions

# version path separator; As mentioned above, this is the character used to split
# version_locations. The default within new alembic.ini files is "os", which uses os.pathsep.
# If this key is omitted entirely, it falls back to the legacy behavior of splitting on spaces and/or commas.
# Valid values for version_path_separator are:
#
# version_path_separator = :
# version_path_separator = ;
# version_path_separator = space
version_path_separator = os  # Use os.pathsep. Default configuration used for new projects.

# set to 'true' to search source files recursively
# in each "version_locations" directory
# new in Alembic version 1.10
# recursive_version_locations = false

# the output encoding used when revision files
# are written from script.py.mako
# output_encoding = utf-8

sqlalchemy.url = sqlite+aiosqlite:///C:/MyFolder/python/discord/logika bot/orm/async_database.sqlite3


[post_write_hooks]
# post_write_hooks defines scripts or Python functions that are run
# on newly generated revision scripts.  See the documentation for further
# detail and examples

# format using "black" - use the console_scripts runner, against the "black" entrypoint
# hooks = black
# black.type = console_scripts
# black.entrypoint = black
# black.options = -l 79 REVISION_SCRIPT_FILENAME

# lint with attempts to fix using "ruff" - use the exec runner, execute a binary
# hooks = ruff
# ruff.type = exec
# ruff.executable = %(here)s/.venv/bin/ruff
# ruff.options = --fix REVISION_SCRIPT_FILENAME

# Logging configuration
[loggers]
keys = root,sqlalchemy,alembic

[handlers]
keys = console

[formatters]
keys = generic

[logger_root]
level = WARN
handlers = console
qualname =

[logger_sqlalchemy]
level = WARN
handlers =
qualname = sqlalchemy.engine

[logger_alembic]
level = INFO
handlers =
qualname = alembic

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic

[formatter_generic]
format = %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s] %(message)s
datefmt = %H:%M:%S
```

**Model that has been changed:**

```py
class Mark(Base):
    __tablename__ = "marks"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    student_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("students.id"))
    lesson_title: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("lessons.title"))
    logiks: Mapped[int]
    date: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(default=datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    presence: Mapped[Optional[bool]]  # <- THIS COLUMN WAS CHANGED

    student: Mapped["Student"] = relationship(back_populates="marks", lazy="joined")
    lesson: Mapped["Lesson"] = relationship(back_populates="marks", lazy="joined")

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"Lesson(title={self.lesson_title!r}, logiks={self.logiks!r}, presence={self.presence!r})"
```

**Migration file:**

```py
"""make presence column in Mark Optional

Revision ID: 9bce8e04e73c
Revises: 5fefb216ecaf
Create Date: 2024-02-02 15:43:40.855715

"""
from typing import Sequence, Union

from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa


# revision identifiers, used by Alembic.
revision: str = '9bce8e04e73c'
down_revision: Union[str, None] = '5fefb216ecaf'
branch_labels: Union[str, Sequence[str], None] = None
depends_on: Union[str, Sequence[str], None] = None


def upgrade() -> None:
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.alter_column('marks', 'presence',
               existing_type=sa.BOOLEAN(),
               nullable=True)
    # ### end Alembic commands ###


def downgrade() -> None:
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.alter_column('marks', 'presence',
               existing_type=sa.BOOLEAN(),
               nullable=False)
    # ### end Alembic commands ###
```

I tried to google the error, but did not find how to fix it with alembic. It would be cool if you could suggest a simple solution to this problem so that I can do migrations without any problems

Thx